# Building DOM dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have about 10 MB of dom elements as a tree view structure - file system. I obviously can't display all of it or paginate the tree view, so I have to build HTML dynamically - show only first level nodes at first and then add first-level children on click.

So I created a map:

```
folderId => leaf HTML
```

So when the user clicks on a root (folder) I dynamically add first level children's HTML from the local storage.

The problem is that I can't add 10 MB map to local storage - I keep getting `QuotaExceededError` error. How could I do something like this?

Comment: Why do you save it in local storage? Just only ajax the html you want to render. How many pages are we talking about? Since 10MB of html sounds like a huge site. Or does that include images and such?

Comment: `I have about 10 MB of dom elements as a tree view structure - file system` how exactly does that look like?

Comment: I think when you are going to click on 2nd leaf then you have to remove 1st leaf from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest build a server side and using ajax to get needed DOM data from server dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax with json and create dynaimic div according to the json data using jquery or javascript.